# Discord.py Reaction Events

Tags: discord, discord.py, pycord

My bot sends an embed every time a new member joins. Then the bot adds the little  reaction to it. I want members to be able to welcome the new member by reacting. If they react, then they will be rewarded in some way. So onto my question, how would I make my bot watch for reactions for 60 seconds after the embed is sent, and what event would I use? I've found a few things in the documentation but none of which seem to make sense to me. A code example and explanation of how it works would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In order to do this, you'd need to make use of the on_reaction_add event, assuming you already have all your imports:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member): # when a member joins
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="welcome") #getting the welcome channel
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Welcome {member.mention}!", color=member.color) #creating our embed

    msgg1 = await channel.send(embed=embed) # sending our embed
    await msgg1.add_reaction("") # adding a reaction


@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    message = reaction.message # our embed
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.channels, name="welcome") #our channel
    if message.channel.id == channel.id: # checking if it's the same channel
        if message.author == bot.user: #checking if it's sent by the bot
            if reaction.emoji.name == "": #checking the emoji
                # enter code here, user is person that reacted
```

I think this would work. I might have done the indentations wrong since I'm on another device. Let me know if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [on_reaction_add()](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_add) event for that. The 60 second feature might be complicated.

If you can get the user object from the joined user the `on_reaction_add()` event, you could check if the user joined less than 60 seconds ago.
You can check the time a user joined with [user.joined_at](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=joined_at#discord.Member.joined_at), and then subtract this from the current time.

Here is how to check how many seconds a user is already on the server.

```py
from datetime import datetime
seconds_on_server = (datetime.now() - member.joined_at).total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather hacky solution is to retrieve the original user who joined through the message on which the reaction is added. Members have the `joined_at` attribute, which is a datetime object, with it you can just snap current datetime and subtract the former from it. The resulting is a timedelta object which you can use to calculate the time difference.